# How do I align equations in a multicols environment

Tags: equations, multicol

I use the following code

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent

    \begin{equation}
    F_{besch}=m_{fzg} \cdot a_{trans}
    \label{eq:trans}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    M_{besch}=\sum_{n=1}^{n}J_{n} \cdot \dot{\omega}_{n}
    \label{eq:rot}
    \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

to write two equations in one line.

[image: Equations are not aligned]

As it can be seen in the picture, the equations are not exactly aligned (propably due to the sum).

How can they be aligned?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a full compilable code, not just a snippet – moreover incomplete.

Comment: do you use`multicols` just to this two equation that they be parallel)?

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you'd like to have just these two equations in parallel. For this, it is better suited to use a `tabular` environment with the `m` column type (from the package `array`):

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{} *2{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}} @{}}
    \begin{equation}
    F_\mathit{besch}=m_\mathit{fzg} \cdot a_\mathit{trans}
    \label{eq:trans}
    \end{equation}
&
    \begin{equation}
    M_\mathit{besch}=\sum_{n=1}^{n}J_{n} \cdot \dot{\omega}_{n}
    \label{eq:rot}
    \end{equation}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're abusing the `multicols` environment. Consider using two side-by-side `minipage` environments -- each of width `0.45\textwidth` -- instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathit{#1}} % to typeset variable names
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}  % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{3} % just for this example

\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:trans}
    F_{\vn{besch}}=m_{\vn{fzg}} \cdot a_{\vn{trans}}
    \vphantom{\sum_1^n} % to balance heights of formulas across the equations
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hfill % maximize horiz. separation between the 'minipage' environments
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:rot}
    M_{\vn{besch}}=\sum_{n=1}^n J_n \cdot \dot{\omega}_n
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use two minipages side  by side and a `\vphantom` in the l.h.s. equation. As your indices look like words, it's better to type them as text.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    F_\text{besch}=m_{fzg} \cdot a_\text{trans}\vphantom{\sum_{n=1}^{n}J_{n}}
    \label{eq:trans}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    M_\text{besch}=\sum_{n=1}^{n}J_{n} \cdot \dot{\omega}_{n}
    \label{eq:rot}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would encase "fzg" in a `\text` directive as well.

Comment: @Mico: I wondered, and thought maybe it's the product of three variables.

Answer (score 4):

Using `multicols` for this is not simple, because of various vertical skips that are added.  I would suggest a couple of `minipages`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}

\begin{document}

Text
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}
      F_{\mathit{besch}}=m_{\mathit{fzg}} \cdot a_{\mathit{trans}}
      \label{eq:trans}
    \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
  \quad
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{equation}
      M_{\mathit{besch}}=\sum_{n=1}^{n}J_{n} \cdot \dot{\omega}_{n}
      \label{eq:rot}
    \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Notice the `b` alignment option to align baselines.

I have also added `\mathit` to your multi-letter supbscripts for better spacing; `\mathrm` may be actually more appropriate depending on the context.

Comment: Is the `center` environment needed? For sure, it will add extra vertical padding, which may not be desirable?

Comment: @Mico Depends on what alignment the OP wants.  Less vertical space would be added by `\noindent\begin{tabular}{c}...\end{tabular}` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`